# Add existing dependencies to bower.json

Tags: bower, bower-install

I accidentally did

```
bower install jquery
```

without the `--save` flag. So this package isn't saved in the dependencies section in bower.json

**Is there a command I can run to add all installed packages into the dependency list?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've written a simple script to scan the installed bower components, and generate the dependency list as a json file.

The code is on Github: [bower-existed-scanner](https://github.com/chuyik/bower-existed-scanner).

Comment: Awesome, this can be really usefull!

Answer (score 3):

Doing again `bower install jquery --save` should do the job.

Comment: yes but this is just one example, suppose I installed multiple packages, how would i sync them all up with the dependency list. i.e add all of the currently installed packages in the dependency list.